# Reactjs functional component default props with props object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In functional components we can pass props like this.

```
function Country(props){

}
```

and we can pass default props value like this

```
function Country({name:'Sri Lanka',description:'blah! blah!'}){
    
}
```

and then we can pass props like this to the component.

```
<Country name={'Germany'} description={'haha...'} />
```

**But I do want to access props' history object. So I did**

```
function Country({name:'Sri lanka',description:'haha',...props}){

}
```

but when I `console.log` `props` it is an empty object. In here I think I may want to pass the `props` object too. How do I do that?

```
<Country name={'Germany'} description={'haha...'} />
```

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean by `props' history object`, can you explain that a bit? Are you saving a history of previous props passed in an array or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to pass props when you use your Country component.

Like this:

```
<Country name={'Germany'} description={'haha...'} {...props} />
```